# Is there a limit for array size in QJson?

Tags: json, qt

I am working with QT 5.5 and I get a json with QNetwork and I try to parse it.
The json object is like this :

```
{
   "cas_version":1008,
   "result":"true",
   "diaporamas":
   {
     "0":
        {
         "diaporamaid":5,
         "diaporamamaj":1440433023,
         "slides":
         {
            "0":{"slideid":32,"slidecontent":"html content here"}
         }
}
}
```

If i run my program with this, no problem, the json is correctly parsed.
But if i have more than 10 elements inside slides, i get this error :"illegal value"
The json is generated by PHP5.5

Thank !

Comment: That sounds odd. If there’s a limit, it’s definitely not 10. Provide an example where it fails.

Comment: There are no such arbitrary limits at all. Most likely, your json is invalid. Please post the entire json object that fails to parse.

Comment: There is a missing `}`.  Also, there are no arrays in this JSON which start with `[`. There are only objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much, it was not an issue in the json part (which is missing a "}"). The problem was when Qt downloading the file, the file was corrupted (I open the buffer too early)